# ubuntu 16.04: Error when importing gtk - libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Reference_Face

Tags: 16.04, python, compiz, gtk

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.
I need to open CompizConfig Settings Manager to enable the unity plugin as my launcher and menu disappeared in the ubuntu desktop.

When I try to open the CompizConfig Settings Manager with

`$ ccsm`

I get the following error message:

```
$ ccsm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ccsm", line 32, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Reference_Face
```

I found that the problem occurs when python tries to import gtk

```
>>> import gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Reference_Face
```

This is the same problem as described here [CompizConfig Settings Manager not opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/881835/compizconfig-settings-manager-not-opening) but now answers were given

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

FT_Reference_Face is a freetype's library.
I uninstalled freetype and the command ccsm did work.
Go to the build directory and run:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Then try ccsm again.
Hope it works.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for the answer and suggestion. I ended up re-installing ubuntu. So I cannot tell if your idea worked, but it is definitely a good hint, so I rated your answer positively (however, it is not shown publicly cause I don't have enough points for that, sorry).